# Any example of SVG used on (popular) sites?

Tags: graphics, svg

I am evaluating the use of SVG for a website I'm working on, and I'd like to see some examples of pages using it effectively. I don't mean a "Sample SVG page" or specific parts like showing chars, but any well done site (not specifically about SVG) that conveys a good graphics experience through the employment of SVG for some or all of its graphics, as an alternative to styling it with PNG/GIF etc.

Answer (score 4):

This question isn't really about programming, so is likely to get closed. Anyway here are a couple of examples:

- http://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2012/tournament-calendar/index.html
- http://hitmo-studio.com
- http://beta.visualize.yahoo.com/core/
- http://evolutionofweb.appspot.com/
- http://www.wheredidmytaxdollarsgo.com/

Comment: the appspot link seems to be the only one left standing.  Are there any examples of major websites making use of SVG at the moment? It seems that everyone has jumped on the canvas bandwagon

Comment: Well, links are not going to stay fresh forever. But these days New York Times, Guardian, Lonely Planet and many others use svg.